# Why "n'ayant pas" is used instead of "qui n'ont pas" in the sentance below

Tags: grammaire, conjugaison, constructions, pronoms-relatifs, participe-présent

**Les données non structurées**:

Elles représentent des informations non organisées n’ayant pas de format prédéterminé

Comment: Both are equivalent and in common daily use. _n'ayant pas_ allows to avoid that "k" sound in _qui_ and thus can sound more fluid to some.

Comment: Agreed; exactly equivalent in meaning. "Data that doesn't have a predetermined format / Data with no predetermined format."